# How to test Converter which uses dependency properties?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8.1, dependency-properties, ivalueconverter

Since multi value converters are not supported on Windows 8.1 apps, I chose to use dependency properties. But later, when I test the converter and I instantiate it, I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to test this kind of converters?

Here is the samplest version of the source code:

```
[TestClass]
public class ConverterWithDependencyPropertyTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void UnitTest()
    {
        var converter = new BinCodeToBinQuantityConverter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your testing code? It seems you are accessing your converter from a non-UI thread.

Comment: I just updated the question with a simple version of the testing code which throws the exception :-)

Comment: What does `BinCodeToBinQuantityConverter` do? According the exception, he tries to access UI-control from a background thread. Use `Dispatcher` for this.

Comment: As I said, I am using a dependency property in this converter, so, this converter inherits from DependencyObject. If I remove the dependency property related source code any exception occurs when I try to invoke the converter, but I need to use it...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could do it so:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Converter_With_Dependency_Property_Test()
    {
        var expectedResult = 3;
        var valueConverted = 0;

        await ExecuteOnUIThread(() =>
        {
            _converterWithDependencyProperty = new ConverterWithDependencyProperty();
            _converterWithDependencyProperty.DependencyProperty = _dummyValue;
            valueConverted = (int)_converterWithDependencyProperty.Convert(_dummyValueToConvert, typeof(int), null, null);
        });

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, valueConverted);
    }

    public static IAsyncAction ExecuteOnUIThread(DispatchedHandler action)
    {
        return CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
    }
```